# Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method must be tokens

Tags: java, python, tomcat, spring-boot, raspberry-pi

Edit: I no longer work at this place, and we switched to node.js anyway, so I cannot verify if anyone's answers are correct. Please vote to close (just need one more).

This is not a duplicate of the other questions (or at least the ones I came across) because I don't use SSL/HTTPS anywhere in my code. I was also able to confirm that these errors are coming from my system and not an outside source (like a bot). If it is something simple then I apologize, I only started using Spring Boot a few months ago.

I am developing an internet of things system where I send a Raspberry Pi Zero W out into the field with sensors. The Raspberry Pi gets sensor data via Bluetooth LE, and HTTP POSTS the data to a Spring Boot server (which is hosted on an AWS EC2 instance). Strangely, the server gets data perfectly fine for a while (in this case, 3 weeks), and then out of nowhere I started getting this exception from Spring/Tomcat:

`2017-06-03 06:17:07.508  INFO 19927 --- [p-nio-80-exec-8]` `o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header`
`Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.`

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens`
        `at` `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11] (rest of the stack trace)`

As I mentioned above, I am not using HTTPS in either Spring Boot or the Raspberry Pi. Since the Raspberry Pi is being deployed to a remote location, I am not changing the code.

The program running on the Raspberry Pi is written in Python, and I use the `requests.post` method to send the data to the server.

I noticed this behavior in an earlier deployment of the system as well, which used an Android device to send the data instead. So I don't think there is anything wrong with the clients...

I have tested the server quite a bit, especially when I add new features, and I never got this error before (except in the previous deployment). Once this error occurs, it seems like it just continues to happen (I lost 3 sensor readings in a row, all at different days/times).

Is data getting corrupted as it leaves the Raspberry Pi? Does `requests.post` have some odd behavior I am unaware of? Does the code I write using Spring affect Tomcat somehow? I have no idea why this is happening and all of the other answers I came across say its usually because of an HTTPS to HTTP connection. My application.properties file only has server.port=80

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Apparently I don't have the reputation to close this yet. I can no longer verify if provided answers are correct. See my comment below. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What does this have to do with python?

Comment: I wrote the IoT Gateway on the Raspberry Pi using Python. Since I was new to Python, I wasn't sure if maybe I was doing something wrong. It doesn't matter since I can no longer verify if anyone's solution is correct, since I don't work at that place anymore.

Comment: I also noticed that I am able to close this question, and I casted my vote to do so. If anyone else is able to vote that would be great. I kind of wish SO gave the OP the option to just close the question themselves, though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP requested to close it.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes this happens when the server is not set up to handle secure requests through https, but the client is sending them that way. When I made that mistake I got a response that looked something like this:

`Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x000xf70x010x110x110xf30x030x030x0e0xef0x9d10x8dV0xff0x000x1d0xcf0xffE0x4!0x5}0xa40xef/0xdf ]. HTTP method names must be tokens`

Comment: I got the same kind of the thing. I set a breakpoint in the debugger, and in my case it was because I had VisualVM running where I was trying to connect with RMI.

Answer (score 2):

Today, I also faced similar issue. I change the URL from https to http and it solved the issue.

Comment: I was testing a webservice with "wss://..." . Your answer made me think about it and change it to "ws://...". Maybe it will help someone else. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Adding a link to better explain my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557485/difference-between-ws-and-wss

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Siraj! Unfortunately I am no longer involved on that project, and we ended up switching to Node.js anyway. I don't know why you were downvoted, so I will upvote you until someone provides an explanation. I will see if I can close this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Increase header buffer size
#server.tomact.max-http-header-size: 8192   this is lose efficacy 
server.max-http-header-size=15360
```

Comment: How will this solve it? And why does it 'lose efficacy'?